# How to mapply through specific elements of a list

Tags: r, indexing, lapply

I'm working to write a function that can easily pull survival estimates at specific timepoints in the presence of a single stratifying variable.  Here's an example:

```
dat <- 
data.frame(time = floor(runif(1000, 1, 101)),
       status = rbinom(1000, 1, p = 0.2),
       group = c("West European", "East European", "African", "Asian", 
                "North American Native", "South American Native")[floor(runif(1000, 1, 7))]
)


head(dat)
   time status                 group
1   44      1         West European
2   67      0         West European
3   98      0 South American Native
4   59      0                 Asian
5   63      1 North American Native
6    5      0 North American Native


fit <- survfit(Surv(dat$time, dat$status) ~ dat$group)

str(fit)

List of 14
$ n        : int [1:6] 151 157 170 171 176 175
$ time     : num [1:488] 1 2 3 7 8 9 10 11 13 14 ...
$ n.risk   : num [1:488] 151 150 149 148 147 145 143 142 141 139 ...
$ n.event  : num [1:488] 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 ...
$ n.censor : num [1:488] 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 1 2 2 ...
$ surv     : num [1:488] 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ type     : chr "right"
$ strata   : Named int [1:6] 78 82 79 80 82 87
 ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:6] "dat$group=African" "dat$group=Asian" 
 "dat$group=East European" "dat$group=North American Native" ...
$ std.err  : num [1:488] 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ upper    : num [1:488] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ lower    : num [1:488] 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ conf.type: chr "log"
$ conf.int : num 0.95
$ call     : language survfit(formula = Surv(dat$time, dat$status) ~ dat$group)
- attr(*, "class")= chr "survfit"
```

As I see it, the result of a call to "survfit" is a list with some elements that contain data, and some elements that contain metadata (like the levels of the stratifying variable, or the function call itself).  I'd like to build a function that can loop through the data-containing elements and arrange them into a nice dataframe.  For example, suppose I want the 6 one-week survival estimates (one for each group).  These occur at indices

```
which(fit$time == 7)
[1]   4  84 166 245 324 408
```

But obviously I can't simply pull these indices from every element of the list.  Is there a convenient way I could create a smaller list containing only prespecified elements of `fit`?  In this case, `fit$time`, `fit$n.risk`, etc. (all the items with 488 elements) would need to be included in the call.

I've made several attempts such as

```
lapply(fit[[c(2, 3, 6)]], function(x) x[which(fit$time == 7)])
```

But keep running into

```
Error in fit[[c(2, 3, 6)]] : recursive indexing failed at level 2
```

Which means I still have a lot to learn about indexing lists. Any ideas on how to access specific elements of a list to be fed through a `lapply` call?

Comment: Also, for what its worth: `set.seed(8765309)`

Comment: ^ Is worth a lot!!!

Comment: you can try this: `lapply(fit[c(2,3,6)],function(x) x[which(x$time ==7)])`